# The URL string changes after ajax call return

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

I have been struggling with a problem for some time. I cannot understand the reason as it happens in a specific case, not with the others.

I have a javascript function that calls a PHP script to upload a file to the server (standard code, have been using it and works perfectly normally).

```
function upload_picture(fieldID, success, error) {

    var folderName;
    switch (fieldID) {
        case "pop_drawing":
            folderName = "pop_dwg";
            break;
        case "pop_installation":
            folderName = "pop_inst";
            break;
        case "pop_picture":
            folderName = "pop_pict";
            break;
    }

    var file_data = $('#' + fieldID).prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('folder', folderName);
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dbh/upload.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function (response) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log (response); // display success response from the PHP script

            if (response.indexOf("yüklendi") > 0) {
                success();
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log (response); // display success response from the PHP script
            error(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The function is called from several points in the code and it works OK except one point. At this particular point when it returns it changes the page URL from

http://localhost/pop/#

to

http://localhost/pop/?pop_drawing=&pop_installation=&pop_picture=Compelis-Logo.jpg&pop_need_special_prod=Hay%C4%B1r&pop_need_application=Hay%C4%B1r&pop_order_made=Evet&pop_approval=4&pop_cost_visible=Hay%C4%B1r#

due to a reason I could not understand. This string in the URL line are some parameters on the web page where I press the button to call the function.

The code which call the function is:

```
function uploadPopPicture () {

    if ($('#pop_picture_label').html() !== 'Seçili dosya yok...') {
        upload_picture('pop_picture', 
        function(){
            console.log('Görsel yüklendi...');
        }, 
        function(error){
            console.log('Error:', error);
        });
    }
}
```

Same code (obviously with different parameters) is used elsewhere in the program and works OK.

Any ideas what I might be missing.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: how is that function called?

Comment: uploadPopPicture () I detailed above calls the function that goes to PHP script

Comment: Ok... How is uploadPopPicture called? Are you using a HTML button with the submit attribute?

Comment: Yes. I do.  And the HTML code is <button class="btnPopUpload" id="btn_pop_picture_upload" onClick="javascript: uploadPopPicture();" style="width: 30px; margin-top: 4px;" disabled></button>

Comment: The disabled attribute changes programmatically once a filename is chosen

Comment: The functions likely doesn't get called `onclick="javascript:...` isn't syntactically correct

Comment: Try removing the `onclick` and see what happens. Maybe there is another event handler attached to the button click. If nothing happens, my suspicion is wrong.

Comment: My apologies. I do  not use a button with submit attribute. It goes to onclick

Comment: BTW, you should attach event handlers via `$().click()` or `$().on()`.

Comment: I do not think onclick is the criminal here :-) as there are different buttons with the same code, that call similar functions. And the returns are OK. That is why I am confused.

Comment: A button's default behaviour is submit. If you don't specify any particular behaviour then that's what it will do. So when clicked it will submit your form, regardless of any JavaScript. Try adding the attribute `type="button"` to your button HTML and see if that helps.

Comment: ADyson. Thank you so much. Adding type="button" has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A button's default behaviour is "submit". If you don't specify any particular behaviour then that's what it will do. So when clicked it will submit your form, regardless of any JavaScript.

Add the attribute `type="button"` to your button HTML and that will stop it from automatically submitting the form.